# Django not creating user profile on user creation despite using signals

Tags: python, django, django-users, user-registration

I am trying to make the user profile to be created automatically as i am creating the user.
I used django signals to do this and imported it in the apps.py file but it still didn't work can you please show me what i did wrong. Thank you.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signal import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

in shell('NewUser2' was created with the registration form, 'Destiny' was given a profile using the admin)

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.filter(username='NewUser2').first()
>>> user
<User: NewUser2>
>>> user.profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
django.contrib.auth.models.User.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.
>>> user.profile.image.url
Traceback (most recent call last):
django.contrib.auth.models.User.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.
>>> user_created_in_admin = User.objects.filter(username='Destiny').first()
>>> user_created_in_admin.profile.image.url 
'/media/default.jpg'
```

Comment: Please check your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file, look if you added your app name like 'appname' or 'appname.apps.AppnameConfig'. e.g. assume your app name is blog, in installed apps add: 'blog.apps.BlogConfig',

Comment: Thank you so much it has been solved